# How do I get images on html page in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm new to Django. I created a web page with Django, now I'm having problems with statically loading files on templates. I don't understand what's the problem because if I put it in only just one folder it works but if I change the directory of that folder it gives me a `404 not found` error. It looks something like this:

```
<img src="/media/{{cat.image_name}}" alt="#" height="350">
```

Here "media" is the folder where my image files are and  `"{{cat.image_name}}"` is the name of that image which is passed through the database and this works.

However, if I write

```
<img src="/admin/public/media/{{cat.image_name}}" alt="#" height="350">
```

were `admin>public>media` is where I have placed my images.

I get this error:

`Not Found: /admin/public/media/freelancer.jpg
[09/Dec/2019 18:23:30] "GET /admin/public/media/freelancer.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1852`

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: What? Why would your images be in "admin/public"? What have you set up to serve images at that URL?

Comment: What are your `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings? And have you done [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django calls these files "staticfiles" and their path conventionally contains "static". These are files that you maintain in your source repository and are not in any way uploaded by users or admins: typically all JS, CSS and image assets for JS/CSS/HTML layout.

How to configure static files is well documented on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/.

Any files that are uploaded by the users/admins (dynamic content) are placed under a path conventionally named "media", as documented on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MEDIA_ROOT.

In your case:

If `/admin/public/media/` is a local file path it is not visible per default in your web server (which is good). File path != URL - which is why there is STATIC_ROOT (file path) and STATIC_URL (the url), and same with MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL. Django takes care that what you provide under the file path STATIC_ROOT is visible under STATIC_URL by default. If you want do not use this mechanism you have to implement it yourself:

1. copy the files from the file path /admin/public/media to a directory that is on your webserver and accessible by the web server
2. implement a URL route - either in Django or in your proxy (Nginx or Apache HTTP)

For larger applications, it is sensible to setup an Nginx or Apache Webserver to serve the static files from a directory in which Django has placed them when running `./manage.py collectstatic`. These proxies serve static files much faster than Django, while the Django server has than more resources to server the dynamic (DB) content.

Answer (score 0):

Django static files work with settings, if you do not add whatever path to your staticfiles dirs it will not work